# Raspberry Pi as Tor Router

Tags: raspbian

Make Magazine recently published an article on how to turn a raspberry pi into a tor router. I'm working my way though, but am stuck on Part 4. I'm able to get wlan1 to show my network name as an available wifi access point, but when I go to log into it it goes from "Connected" back to "Saved,Secure" but won't actually connect to the signal.

Here is the link to the instructions:
http://makezine.com/projects/browse-anonymously-with-a-diy-raspberry-pi-vpntor-router/

I've been following them exactly, but it just doesn't seem to work. I've also tried fiddling with some of the ip address since I think there may be typos.

Comment: Welcome to rpi.SE! Please provide more info on what command fails and what error messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [OpenWrt + Tor en una Raspberry Pi](http://www.it-cave.com/openwrt-tor-en-una-raspberry-pi/). I think it's easier to understand and at the bottom you've got SD images ready to go ;-).
Remember you can translate pages with Chrome.